# How to access a shared lib(.so) file function in RStudio?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, rstudio, rcpp

I have a function in my .so file declared as

```
     func_signature namespace_name::class_name::function_name(){
             /* some code here*/
     }
```

I want to call this function with function_name() in my RStudio deploying a RShiny app. How do I call this function as in the syntax and statement for it?

Comment: also would be useful to add some shiny code both `server.R` and `ui.R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
  dyn.load("testme.so")
  testme <- function() {   
     result <- .Call("testme")
  }
```

Comment: Will try that and let you know!! Thanks